# Adding header footer and content to split layout

Tags: html, css

I would like to add a header and footer to this split layout like that:
[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGysn.png)

When I add this code:

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
div#header{
width:100%;
height:65px;
position:fixed;
z-index:100;
background-color:#F00;
 } 

div#footer{
width:100%;
height:65px;
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
background-color:#06F;
}
div#content{
background-color:#111;
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:absolute;
    }
</style>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <?php include 's/header.php';?>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
    <?php include 'index.html';?>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <?php include 's/footer.php';?>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

I have header and footer only after I clicked not in the split screen:
[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQXGo.png)

Comment: What's you question exactly? Please limit it to a certain point and set up a running code example, instead pasting your whole code.

Answer (score 0):

I change the content as folow

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="columns-container">
    <div class="column column-a"></div>
    <div class="column column-b"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and add the follow css

```
#columns-container {
  position:relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.column {
  position: absolute;
}
.column-a {
  background-color: green;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 50%;
  left: 0;
}

.column-b {
  background-color: yellow;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 50%;
}
```

On this URL a working sample

https://jsfiddle.net/vfh2ma1x/

Answer (score 0):

In the content I would like add this layout from tympanus, [linc to code](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/10/25/split-layout/) but when I add `'. The layout is on full page, and I would like to limit all content from tympanus site only to content div, like on picture [final pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7n2j.png).

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <?php include 's/header.php';?>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
    <?php include 'index.html';?> // link to split site from tympanus
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <?php include 's/footer.php';?>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```